# Objective-C:How to Converting int to id for selector's object?

Tags: objective-c

I received a return value from SQLite fetch

```
int primaryKey = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
```

and I'm going to use it as a selector's object:

```
[[ABC alloc] performSelector:@selector(abcWithAAA:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:primaryKey]];
```

the NSLog result for primarykey is a number 4:

```
NSLog(@"primaryKey：%i",primaryKey);
4
```

but the NSLog result for [NSNumber numberWithInt:primaryKey] is 131628896.

why? and how do i convert the int value correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

131628896 is the memory address of the NSNumber object.

use:

```
- (void)abcWithAAA: (NSNumber *)number {
      int primaryKey = [number intValue];
      NSLog("%i", primaryKey);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I solved the problem using an adapter method that does the cast for the withObject method.
My problem was that I wanted to use a typedef enum and pass it as value to the withObject.

I wanted to call this method using the performSelect message:

```
-(void) requestInfosAndPersistByMonsterType:(MonsterTypes)monsterType {

}
```

As you see it request a MonsterTypes typedef defined like this:

```
typedef enum
{
    MonsterTypeIWerwolf = 0,
    MonsterTypeITempler = 1,
    MonsterTypeIUndefined,
} MonsterTypes;
```

Actually to be able to call the method above I build this adapter that calls it then:

```
   -(void)monsterTypeFromObject:(id)_monsterType {
        if ([_monsterType respondsToSelector:@selector(intValue)]) {
            int _t = [_monsterType intValue];
            switch (_t) {
                case MonsterTypeIWerwolf:
                    _t = MonsterTypeIWerwolf;
                    break;
                case MonsterTypeITempler:
                    _t = MonsterTypeITempler;
                    break;
                default:
                    _t = MonsterTypeIUndefined;
                    break;
            }
            [self requestInfosAndPersistByMonsterType:_t];
        }
    }
```

It is used this way:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(monsterTypeFromObject:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:monsterType] afterDelay:5.0f];
```

You can find it explained in more detail here:
http://kerkermeister.net/objective-c-adapter-from-nsinteger-to-id-when-using-performselector-withobject/

Answer (score 2):

When you log `[NSNumber numberWithInt:primaryKey]`, you're logging the address of an NSNumber object.  If you want to see what's inside it should be `[[NSNumber numberWithInt:primaryKey] intValue]`.

In other words, there's nothing in that to suggest your conversion is a problem.

Comment: the selector won't allow to use a int as a id object for withObject. so i got this error "Implicit conversion of 'int' to 'id' is disallowed with ARC"

Comment: You seemed to be asking why the numbers were different.  [shrug]

Answer (score 2):

`[NSNumber numberWithInt:primaryKey]` is object.
use `%@` for objects.

```
NSLog(@"%@", [NSNumber numberWithInt:primaryKey]);
```

Comment: NSNumber *pk = [NSNumber numberWithInt:primaryKey];
the result of NSLog(@"pk：%@",pk); is also 4.

Comment: NSLog(@"%d",primaryKey); and NSLog(@"%@", [NSNumber numberWithInt:primaryKey]); will give you same output.